# TP-Link Archer T2U adapter not showing AP support in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, realtek-wireless, wireless-access-point, hostapd, mediatek

Kernel version : 4.2.0-27-generic

After running command "iw list"on terminal it shows :

Supported interface modes:

```
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * monitor
```

Not showing AP but it supports AP mode.

Comment: If you are indeed running Ubuntu - you need to update & upgrade your system. Kernel 4.2 reached EOL back in 2016 and has been unsupported for a long time. Are you running Ubuntu or another distro (Mint 17.3 for example)  -- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

Comment: using ubuntu 14.04.